# Unable to pass resolved parameter from controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, http-post, angularjs-ng-repeat

The page is not loading at all. I m trying to do resolve for an HTTP service.

My Factory :

```
app.factory("search", function($q, $http, $cookieStore){
return {
    getMessage: function(){
        //return $q.when("Response");
        console.log("Cookie --> ".$cookieStore.get("sId"));
        var promise = $http.post('tpl/processors/process-contacts.php', {sid : $cookieStore.get("sId")}).then(function(response) {              
            return response.data;               
        });
        return promise;
    }
   }
});
```

My state where I do resolve:

```
  .state('app.mail.compose', {
            url: '/compose',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/mail_new.php',
            reloadOnSearch: true,
            resolve: {     
                searchVal: ['search',  function (search) {
                      return search.getMessage(); // not then
                }]
            }
        })
```

My controller :

```
 app.controller('SmsNewCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$cookieStore','$stateParams','searchVal',         function($scope, $http, $cookieStore,$stateParams,searchVal,transformRequestAsFormPost) {
$scope.sId = $cookieStore.get("sId");
//console.log("Inbox Type : "+ $stateParams.inboxType );
console.log("Cookie Call inside SmsNewCtrl: ",$cookieStore.get("sId"));


    $scope.contacts =  searchVal;
    console.log("Contacts from Search Factory :" + $scope.contacts);


    $scope.mail = {
      to: '',
      content: ''
    }

}]);
```

Earlier I used to do the http call inside my controller. Till then everything worked fine but the page loaded first and data came after that. So I wanted to resolve the data by doing http call outside controller. I m new to Angular and still learning, please let me know if my approach is wrong or let me know the best way to do a http post outside controller and resolve.

Comment: The fact that the data are coming after the page is loaded is perfectly normal when processing http calls since everything is processed asynchronously. It is even a very good practice. With your previous code you could use a value in the scope initially equal to {} and then fill it when the promise resolves, angular will automatically upadte the view if you use this scope value in the view.

Comment: you did not set the controller in your state declaration + in your controller the number of arguments you are injecting, does not match the number of arguments of the actual function

Comment: @JohnDoe90 I have set the controller and added relevant injections but still it doesn't work. I m getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick example which is working:
http://jsbin.com/nuzaqugofu/1/edit?html,js,console

Try it the way I did it and keep adding more and more of your code until it does not work anymore. Then you will know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Many thanks Jonn. It is able to resolve but after resolving it does not pass data to the controller. It gives error -  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: messageProvider <- message
Do i have to explicitly inject this resolved variable in controller.

Comment: @SunilMishra that means that it cannot inject the messageProvider. Did you maybe inject `message` to the controller but did not name it `message` in the `resolve` block?

Comment: Hi John, I did exactly as per your example. This is my resolve: resolve: {     
                       message: function(testService) {
                               return testService.getMessage();
                       }
                   }
This is my controller :
.controller('testController', function($scope,message) {
 console.log("FINAL MESSAGE",message);
})

Comment: Is it maybe related to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289357/angular-ui-router-resolve-throwing-provider-error If not I dont really know how to help you any further without the code, sorry

Comment: Thanks @JohnDoe90 ! Your working example and hints helped me solve the issue. Really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `deferred.resolve(data)`:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var promise = $http.post('tpl/processors/process-contacts.php', {sid : $cookieStore.get("sId")}).then(function(response) { 
    deferred.resolve(response);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Then in your controller:

```
var promise = search.getMessage();
promise.then(function(data) {
    // do stuff
}, function() {
    console.log('An error occurred while processing the request.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code but it does not work. Should it be $q.resolve(response.data)? Also, is my resolve configured properly?

Comment: $http returns a promise itself, so he does not have to create one manually

Comment: @martynas I have edited my question according to your answer. Could you please review it.